# Purpose of setFetchMode & setResultTransformer

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Sorry for this basic question. What is the purpose of `setFetchMode` in hinernate?

I saw the types like join, lazy and eager. Is it related to joins? If anyone can provide any links or pdfs that would also do.

Answer (score 0):

`setResultTransformer` helps transforms the result set.

For example:

Calling

```
setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP).list()
```

will return a list of maps. Which helps in looping thru the resultset with column alias.

Pseudo code:

```
Query searchQuery = sessionFactory.currentSession.createQuery(strQuery.toString()).setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)
List searchList = query.list()
query.setParameter("location", params.location)

Map<String,Object> map= new HashMap<String,Object>();
for (Object object : searchList )
{
  map= (Map<String,Object>)object;
  System.out.println(map.get(“location”));
}
```